# Switch between UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

The main functionality of my app is controlled by a UITabBarController.  However, I need to load a View that has a UINavigationController.  When I return to my UITabBarController using

```
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

My UITabBarController no longer responds to clicks.  It seems like the View does not have focus.

However, if I use this code to switch back to the UITabBarController:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]
```

My buttons will respond.  I feel like "addSubview" is less efficient because I never remove the view from the window and therefore it must be adding a second copy of the view to the stack.  Am I correct?  Is there a way to use the first method and make my buttons respond?  Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you're presenting the Nav Controller incorrectly.  You definitely shouldn't be adding views directly to the window. You want to present it using

```
[myTabBarController presentModalViewController:myNavController animated:YES];
```

When you're done with the nav controller you dismiss it with

```
[myTabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and everything should work.

BTW, this is all documented in the docs for UIViewController and the "View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS" document.

Comment: n8gray... you just saved my life.  Perfect.  I was simply opening the nav controller wrong.  I really appreciate it.  You may want to edit the post to remove that dash  in this line:  [myTabBarController - dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Mayer YOU can help me... Every Time I try to `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, I'm getting this error: 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'presentedViewController for controller is itself on dismiss for: <UINavigationController:…

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but it sounds like maybe you've somehow presented the view controller from itself?